# Flex/PHP: dynamic endpoint URL without services-config.xml

Tags: php, apache-flex

how would I change/specify the endpoint URL at runtime in a Flex App which communicates with PHP?
I always used a services-config.xml so far.

I tried to overwrite the endpoint in the mxml Remote Object, with no success.

I also tried to add a new channel set to the Remote Object, but then I needed to define a destination somehow.

Help much appreciated.

Martin

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue and here's what emerged from my struggle ;)

```
public static function getRemoteObject(destination:String, channelName:String,
    showBusyCursor:Boolean=true):RemoteObject{
    var remoteService:RemoteObject=new RemoteObject(destination);
    var channelSet:ChannelSet=new ChannelSet();
    var amf:AMFChannel=new AMFChannel(channelName,
        "http://{server.name}:{server.port}" +
        (Application.application as Application).parameters.contextRoot +
        "/graniteamf/amf");
    channelSet.addChannel(amf);
    remoteService.channelSet=channelSet;
    remoteService.showBusyCursor=showBusyCursor;
    return remoteService;
}
```

So as you can see, I basically do just the things you said you've tried, with my endpoint being partially provided in flashVars at application startup.

Comment: thx for the answer. I have the problem with the destination String. What do you set it to? I have no services-config.xml, so it always gives me an error, the messaging destination was not found.
What's your destination? (How do you invoke this RemoteObject), and where do you set the source (Remote Class)?

Comment: Well, I must admit that I'm confused right now. I thought that you didn't want to use service-config.xml at compile time but I see that you don't want to use it at all and I don't know if it is even possible not to have it at the server side.

Comment: Well - I am using ZendAMF and PHP, so I am ok with using the service-config.xml file. But so far I only had it compiled into the Flex App. It was not located on the server. With this approach, do I need to put it on the server?? Have never thought of this, how/where would I put it.?

Comment: Ok. Sorry, my bad, I am myself Java developer and in case of Java it's mandatory for services-config.xml to be on the server. This way providing it at compile time is not necessary. I thought that in case of PHP it works similarly but unfortunately (as I'm reading through Zend documentation) it does not. Sorry again for speaking about something I have not the slightest idea about :(

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this post because i'm looking for a way that does not use this services-config.xml file.
Wich for deployement purpose can be a real problem and I came across this post :
http://gertonscorner.wordpress.com/2008/09/06/remoteobject-using-amfphp-and-actionscript-3/

Just to help those who googled their way here ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could get it to work, in the generated stub for your service:

```
import com.adobe.fiber.core.model_internal;
```

Also:

```
    /**
 * Override super.init() to provide any initialization customization if needed.
 */
protected override function preInitializeService():void
{           
    _needWSDLLoad = false; // to prevent loading the default WSDL
    super.preInitializeService();
    // Initialization customization goes here
    wsdl = "http://localhost/yourservice?wsdl";
    _needWSDLLoad = true;
    model_internal::loadWSDLIfNecessary();
```

Answer (score 0):

as simple as amfphp style :

```
   gateway = new NetConnection();
   gateway.connect("http://localhost/ZServer/");
   gateway.call("MyService.getData", new Responder(getLoan, onFault));

   public function getLoan(result:Array):void {
                dpDataRaw = new ArrayCollection(result);
            }
```